# WebStorm 10 - shortcut "open by class name" for AngularJS factories, controller,

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

In WebStorm 9 I could search and open my angular modules/factories/controller by name using <kbd>STRG+N</kbd>.

Now, with WebStorm 10.0.1 that's not possible. Someone has a tip for me? I need this shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The key maps are define in File/Settings

Then use the search field with `keymap`, then set the combination of key you are use to for any setting, like opening a class.

Also in the screen there is a drop down that allow you to have the default keymaps settings from other IDE.

Comment: the keymap is not the problem. STRG+N is default for "Class..." aka open class by name. but it doesn't work for angular "classes" anymore

Comment: Works fine with typescript, I'm not in an AngularJS project.

Answer (score 0):

angular modules/factories/controller are now recognized as "symbols". so i've swapped the shortcuts (STRG+ALT+SHIFT+N <> STRG+N). it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

That is right, angular "classes" are now symbols. However, if you want to achieve old behavior, add @class into doc comment. For example

```
/**
 * @class  loginCtrl
 */
```

Might be ugly and might be messing with your documentation, though.